# What is correct web-app file structure? And why?

Tags: php, file, web-applications, filesystems, directory-structure

What is a typical file structure for a web-app?

You've got your brouchure websites:

[+] root

```
 [+] images
 [+] css
 [+] javascripts
 [+] pages
     - index.html
     - biographies.html
     - contacts.html
```

And you've got your web-apps (**what goes here?** This is my understanding):

[ +] root

```
[+]  build 
     [+] classes
         - Database.php
         - User.php
     [+] includes
         - config.php
[+]  public
     [+] css
     [+] js
     [+] img
     [+] pages
         - index.php
         - eventpage.php
         - createabear.php
```

Comment: "Yes, that looks good". However, see the FAQ for why this is being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one "correct" structure.